# Строка подключения MS SQL Server в локальной сети

Tags: c#, windows, sql-server

1. Как должна выглядеть строка подключения к MS SQL Server 2008 при условии, что экземпляр MS SQL Server установлен на одном из удалённых компьютеров, расположенных в локальной сети? (Подключаемся к экземпляру с удалённого компьютера в той же локальной сети).
2. Изменится ли строка подключения,  если для входа в учётную запись windows компьютера, на котором установлен экземпляр MS SQL Server, требуется ввести логин и пароль пользователя, если да, то как?

Comment: Добавьте информацию о способе авторизации на MS SQL сервере. Имею ввиду проверка подлинности Windows или SQL?

Comment: @XelaNimed , по-моему проверка подлинности windows, но могу ошибаться, если владеете информацией по обоим способам, дайте ответ для двух случаев. Спасибо

Comment: [Connection String Syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Повторюсь, но как уже указал @Streletz все возможные виды подключений есть [здесь](https://www.connectionstrings.com).

> Как должна выглядеть строка подключения к MS SQL Server 2008 при условии, что экземпляр MS SQL Server установлен на одном из удалённых компьютеров, расположенных в локальной сети? (Подключаемся к экземпляру с удалённого компьютера в той же локальной сети).

```
Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DbName;Integrated Security=True
```

или при использовании проверки подлинности SQL сервера

```
Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DbName;User ID=uname;Password=pwd
```

- `DataSource` может быть задан как:

  - как в примере указывать на имя сервера;
  - IP-адрес с портом: `192.168.200.100,1433`;
  - `(localdb)\MsSqlLocalDB` для подключения к именованному экземпляру LocalDB
    *(например к тому, что устанавливается с Visual Studio)*;
- `Initial Catalog` имя базы данных;
- `Integrated Security` указывает на то, что необходимо использовать проверку подлинности Windows. В этом случае `User ID` и `Password` не указываются;
- в приложениях можно использовать дополнительные параметры, которые помогают фильтровать запросы к БД при профилировании:

  - `Application Name=MyApplication;`
  - `Workstation ID=PC-NAME`

---

> Изменится ли строка подключения, если для входа в учётную запись windows компьютера, на котором установлен экземпляр MS SQL Server, требуется ввести логин и пароль пользователя, если да, то как?

Могу быть не прав, но мне кажется, что нет, т.к. Вы подключаетесь к SQL серверу, а не открываете сессию удалённого доступа. Если нет явной необходимости, то используйте проверку подлинности Windows для доступа к БД.

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ на вопрос 1**

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;
```

Пример взял [отсюда](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/).

**Ответ на вопрос 2**

Зависит от используемого типа авторизации.

Comment: Спасибо за источник, попробую, если получится, помечу как ответ.